# How to find and select table from Document in Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm creating a function in Google Apps Script. The purpose of this function is selecting the table from the document and move values to the created Spreadsheet. The problem is that I can't get the table from the document (debugging is OK, but logs show selected table as empty `{}`).

```
    function addAnswersTable() {
    var File = function(Path) { // File object constructor
        this.Path = Path;
        this.Doc = DocumentApp.openById(this.Path);
        this.getTable = new function()
        // This function defines 
        // a getTable method to get 
        // the first table in the Document
        {
            if (this.Doc != undefined) {
                var range = this.Doc.getBody();
                var tables = range.getTables();
                var table = tables[0];
                return table;
            }
        }
    }
    // Creating Excel Table, where first column
    // of selected table should be moved
    var Table = SpreadsheetApp.create("AnswersTable");
    // Creating new File object
    var TrueAnswersFile = new File
    ('1_ne9iBaK-Z36yUYrISr3gru3zw3Qdsneiu14sWnjn34');
    // Calling getTable method to get the table placed in File 
    var TrueAnswersTable = TrueAnswersFile.getTable;
    for (var i = 1; i <= TrueAnswersTable.getNumRows; i++) {
        // Filling spreadsheet "A" column with cells'
        // values ​​from table stored in File
        Table.getActiveSheet().getRange("A" + i).setValue(TrueAnswersTable.getCell(1, i).getValue());
    };
    }
```

I except the output in Spreadsheet column "A" like :

A1. Just
A2. Cells'
A3. List item with
A4. Values From Table

Actually spreadsheet is empty

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. Can you explain about the result (``getTable = {Cell 1,Cell 2..,Cell   n}``) you want? I cannot understand about ``{Cell 1,Cell 2..,Cell   n}``. Can you provide a sample result? 2. If your question is to retrieve a table (or values of table?) from Google Document, can you do the script to more simple? Because the unused variables are included in your script. I think that providing simple script will help users think of your solution.

Comment: Thank you for attention. I have made some change based on your advice. Hope it will be easier to understand for you

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating your question. From your updated question, I proposed the modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? At first, please check whether my understanding for your question is correct. If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the values from the column "A" of Google Document and put the values to the column "A" of the created Spreadsheet.
- The table of index `0` in the Document has 4 rows and 1 column.

  - The values of each row is `Just, Cells', List item with, Values From Table`.

I could understand like above. If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- In your script, the method is not used as the function. By this, the method is not run.

  - For example, `TrueAnswersFile.getTable` and `TrueAnswersTable.getNumRows`.
- No method is used.

  - For example, `getValue()` of `TrueAnswersTable.getCell(1, i).getValue()`.
- `new` of `this.getTable = new function()` is not required.
- In your script, `getCell(1, i)` of `TrueAnswersTable.getCell(1, i)` retrieves the values at from column "B" of the row 2.

  - If you want to retrieve the values from the row 1 of the column "A", please modify to `getCell(i - 1, 0)`. But in this modification, the start of index is `0`. So you can use `getCell(i, 0)`.
- When `setValue()` is used in the for loop, the process cost becomes high. In your case, you can use `setValues()` instead of it.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function addAnswersTable() {
  var File = function(Path) {
    this.Path = Path;
    this.Doc = DocumentApp.openById(this.Path);
    this.getTable = function() { // Modified
      if (this.Doc != undefined) {
        var range = this.Doc.getBody();
        var tables = range.getTables();
        var table = tables[0];
        return table;
      }
    }
  }
  var Table = SpreadsheetApp.create("AnswersTable");
  var TrueAnswersFile = new File('1_ne9iBaK-Z36yUYrISr3gru3zw3Qdsneiu14sWnjn34');
  var TrueAnswersTable = TrueAnswersFile.getTable();
  var values = []; // Added
  for (var i = 0; i < TrueAnswersTable.getNumRows(); i++) { // Modified
    values.push([TrueAnswersTable.getCell(i, 0).getText()]) // Modified
  };
  Table.getRange("A1:A" + values.length).setValues(values); // Added
}
```

#### References:

- [getCell(rowIndex, cellIndex)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table#getCell(Integer,Integer))
- [getText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table-cell#getText())
- [Benchmark: Reading and Writing Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)